To use gallery view on Chrome/Chromium browsers, SharedArrayBuffer is required
I am integrating zoom into laravel with server to server auth. But i start the meeting this error is occur in console.
https://github.com/gzuidhof/coi-serviceworker
I include this file in blade file.
i am using the latest cdn of zoom for front end handling the launch the meeting.
